# Creating a tangram with Three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry, webgl, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I need to create a tangram-like object, in which a user could be able to manipulate the structure, in order to create configurations as those you can see [here](http://fill-o-tactics.tumblr.com/post/125867104794/vargram).

I'm trying to understand which strategy would be best for writing the code with Three.JS, remembering that in the best case I would like to add physics.

I'm really new to WebGL, any advice would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/livinglegendparagon/full/JKEZPa/

```
$sizeOfYourContainer: 1000;
$s: $sizeOfYourContainer;
$Area: sqrt($s * $s);
$a: $Area / 8;
$b: $Area / 4;
```

This has good links for the formula for a true tangram, this above formula will give you a and b values based off of how wide/height you want your container